# Error with installing gems

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems

```
greg@greg-VirtualBox:~$ gem install twitter
/home/greg/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /home/greg/.rvm/bin/gem: Argument list too long
/home/greg/.rvm/bin/gem: line 6: /home/greg/.rvm/bin/gem: Success
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok thanks for clarifying it. I first thought you had access to the GUI interface. In that case try remove all .rvm from your user's folder, and try re-install.
Let me how it goes.

Comment: this is in the terminal, what you talking bout?

Comment: I modified my answer based on your comment. I hope it helps. I am trying :)

Comment: like sudo reinstall ruby-rvm?

Comment: try it without usig the sudo command. and see if that works ...if that does not work then try it with sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `gem install t`. I hope that's what you are looking for [The Twitter Ruby Gem](http://sferik.github.com/twitter/)